# Bundle VF page with public sites in AppExchange Managed Package

Tags: webservices, force.com-sites, appexchange, apex-webservice

We have a requirement for an AppExchange product. 
We plan to bundle the Salesforce functionality as managed package and some part of the requirements as a secure but public widget that can be embedded in any website.

This secure widget would display data from the Salesforce org and also have the functionality to save data to the Salesforce org where the managed package is installed. 
How can we package widget/web form to distribute it via the AppExchange?

Can we include a public VF page or Public Web Service as a part of managed package? If yes, we can provide a widget (code snippet) to call public web service/web page.